# How to automatically grant full script access permissions to specific approved users?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am an ex developer of 20 years thats made a temporary return to coding to build a solution for a small family business.

Part of this solution is a simple front end to generate Quotes and Invoices from data collected from a Sheet UI, using a Template Spreadsheet and then copying , populating and renaming etc.

The Template Spreadsheet is a "smart" document as it has code attached which runs when the sheet is opened, creating menus to provide additional functions create a workflow form the main app and so on.

The problem I am having is that the copied Spreadsheet is needing authorisation the first time it is run, something I want to avoid as the whole purpose of this app is to make it faster and easier for very low tech users (my 78 yo Father for one) and expecting them to deal with multiple step prompts for authorisation will not cut it.

I am coding as one user (lets say IC1) and the end use will be logged in as IC2.

How do I set this up so the newly generated Spreadsheets have full access and don't prompt when first run?

Comment: If you [deploy the addon](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-addons#publishing_instructions) domain wide they should only have to do the authorization step once at install or first run.

Comment: Chris they use a consumer account all under a single id.

Comment: That *should* be okay. When you go to publish it you can [set the visibility](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/publication-categories#published_add-on_visibility) to 'Private'. Here is an example from my dashboard: https://i.imgur.com/P7SnBqJ.png.